# Deploy through GitHub Pages returns 404 Not Found Page

Tags: github-pages

Here is my github:
https://github.com/changan1111/DeployGHPage

i am able to successfully publish using ngh --dir dist/ng-fundamentals

It returns successfully published and I am seeing a branch ghPages..

when i open the url https://changan1111.github.io/DeployGHPage/ i am seeing empty page.

What is the wrong in this? can any please help on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open https://changan1111.github.io/DeployGHPage/ instead. Your app is working here. Note that it can take some time (10-15min) between the enabling of GitHub Pages and the URL working.

Comment: ,, Thanks .. i am seeing still empty page...  i did not see after 15 mins as well.  do we need to wait for again 15 mins if we refresh

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I have given the screenshot. can u pls check?

Comment: Finally it came after 10 mins. can we reduce the wait time?

Comment: not really. clear your cache regularly and that's the only thing... :(